# How to Retrieve data from Firebase database to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to Retrieve data from Fire-base database to Unity.
How to Update data in Firebase database from Unity.

Answer (score 2):

[To retrieve data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data), **Retrieving Data** section.

> Firebase data is retrieved by either a one time call to GetValueAsync() or attaching to an event on a FirebaseDatabase reference. The event listener is called once for the initial state of the data and again anytime the data changes.

[To save data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data), **Saving Data** section.

> There are five methods for writing data to the Firebase Realtime
>   Database:
>
> `SetValueAsync() -- Write or replace data to a defined path, such as
>   users/<user-id>/<username>.`
>
> `SetRawJsonValueAsync() -- Write or replace data with raw Json, such
>   as users/<user-id>/<username>.`
>
> `Push()   Add to a list of data. Every time you call Push(), Firebase
>   generates a unique key that can also be used as a unique identifier,
>   such as user-scores/<user-id>/<unique-score-id>.`
>
> `UpdateChildrenAsync() -- Update some of the keys for a defined path
>   without replacing all of the data.`
>
> `RunTransaction() -- Update complex data that could be corrupted by
>   concurrent updates.`